# Calling a segue everytime a table cell in an array is clicked - swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, segue

I'm trying to call on a segue every time a cell in my array is clicked. I keep getting to errors.

1. Type 'addPRTableViewController?' has no member text.
2. Value of type 'String' can never be nil, Comparison isn't allowed.

Here's my code

Viewcontroller I want to segue FROM when a cell is clicked

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let text = "Your text"
    performSegueWithIdentifier("YourSegue", sender: text)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YourSegue" {
        let yourOtherVC = segue.destinationViewController as? addPRTableViewController
        if let text = sender as? String {
            addPRTableViewController?.text = text // Error 1
        }
    }
}
```

View Controller I want to segue TO when a cell in the other view controller is clicked

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    txtPR.delegate = self

    var text = String() 


    if text != nil { // Error 2
        txtPR.text = text

    }

}
```

I'm not quite sure why I'm getting this. Any info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code. Here is the correct one:

```
class viewController: UIViewController{

var text:String = ""

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    text = "Your text"
    performSegueWithIdentifier("YourSegue", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if segue.identifier == "YourSegue" {
    let yourOtherVC = segue.destinationViewController as? addPRTableViewController
        yourOtherVC?.text = text
  }
}
```

And in your addPRTableViewController

```
class addPRTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var text:String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    txtPR.delegate = self

    if text != nil {
        txtPR.text = text!
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

PerformSegueWithIdentifier takes your view controller as a second argument not string :

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("YourSegue", sender: self)
```

Also your prepareforsegue is wrong.Add a text property in your firstViewController and use it like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if segue.identifier == "YourSegue" {
    let yourOtherVC = segue.destinationViewController as? addPRTableViewController
        yourOtherVC?.text = self.text
  }
}
```

Finally you secondViewcontroller has to have a property text:

```
class addPRTableViewController : UIViewController {
    var text:String
    ....
}
```

Comment: I still get the error  'type "yourOtherVC" has no member "text" '

Comment: You have to create the text property in your viewController class. As show above

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things wrong here, easy mistakes to make when you are just starting out though.

The variable text in the viewController you are segueing to is declared in viewDidLoad, this means it doesn't exist before or after viewDidLoad is called, causing the first error (the class doesn't have the variable text as it is 'owned' by viewDidLoad).

To fix this declare text above viewDidLoad.

The second error is because you declared text to be a non-optional type String, so it can never be nil. This is fine if you know that in every case text will be set when you segue. Otherwise declare it as 'String?'

Eg:

```
var text: String? 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    txtPR.delegate = self

    if text != nil {
        txtPR.text = text!
    }
}
```